# Change connectionstring based on TransactionScope in WCF project (baseHttpBinding)

Tags: c#, wcf, connection-string, transactionscope

In entire application use the static class `tConfig.ConnectionString` to download the necessary connectionstring. Unfortunately, I need to be able to modify connectionsting depending on whether the reference is to the `TransactionScope`. Currently, I have this piece of code, but static class calls me StackOverflow error. Please help to implement the functionality in this class static (or some better solution).

```
public static class tConfig
{   
    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get {
            if (System.Transactions.Transaction.Current != null)
                return "ConnectionString with scope";
            else
                return "ConnectionString without scope";
        }
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData;

    [OperationContract]
    string GetDataWithScope;
}


public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public string GetData
    {
        using (var context = new MyEntities(tConfig.ConnectionString)
        {
            return context.table1.where(x=>x.ID == 1).Select(x=> x.F_NAME).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
        }
    }

    public string GetDataWithScope
    {
        using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600)))
        {
            using (var context = new MyEntities(tConfig.ConnectionString)
            {
                return context.table1.where(x=>x.ID == 1).Select(x=> x.F_NAME).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use transactionScope for select operation?

Comment: It's only example. I use it for AddObject and update

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is bad idea to use transdactions this way. When the transaction completes? in your code there is no Complete or RollBack call. The scope for every call will be different because of different threads of each call.

see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384250.aspx). It describes the approach to use trasactions on wcf level. 
In this situation client can create and complete transaction scope.